# Trigger job after all data as been processed

Tags: architecture

So we have a few systems(around 6) that outputs information as files to our FTP, once a files is received it is instantly processed and the output is stored in the database and the source file is deleted. Another applications needs to run a specific job every night, however, it should start the job only if all the files from source system have been processed. 
SO the solution to this would be to poll the database to see if the files have been processed and once we know everything is done, we trigger the job.

My question is, is there a better way of doing this? maybe a message based approach?
The approach i am looking for is not for just this system, a few more systems also needs to trigger jobs once data from source system as arrived , so i am looking at a scalable solution.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to put the trigger for jour nightly jobs into the database import logic for each database import/file processing.

Your nightly job would need a check for completeness of imports, i.e. that all files are imported correctly.

With this you would not need to poll anymore, instead you would call the completeness check for each imported file.

Watch out for race conditions, make sure that two imports finishing in parallel don't trigger the night job in parallel.